# Directory/file naming conventions when storing media collection on Linux

Tags: linux, debian, directory-structure

I am building a NAS/HTPC that will operate under Debian (Wheezy, probably). I am trying to design the directory schema for what will be stored on the server so that everything is nice and uniform for whatever media playback software I choose to use (probably XBMC).

From what I have read of the FHS, it looks like `/srv/` might be the most appropriate place to store media exports, but I'm not sure.

Everyone in the family will have their own `home` directory, which I will use to set up syncing (hence backup) of their Windows 'My Documents' directories. Backup will be provided by software RAID5 with a big LV.

Since everyone might want to watch media from their own computer, I want it to look friendly to Windows as well as Linux. I suggest that rules out spaces in directory names at least but what about filenames?

So far I have come up with:

```
/srv/media/TV-Shows/Show Name/Season 1/Some Show.avi
- - - - - /Movies/Movie Title (2012)/Movie File.avi
- - - - - /Music/[various]/ nb. *my music folder is a ludicrous mess*
- - - - - /Photos/Mum/whatever/foo.png
```

I think Photos and Music might be a different kettle altogether - I wonder if they should store their own pictures in a directory under their `home` path or should use a unified directory of Photos on a share and then a subdir of their own name from then if necessary, or separated by whatever the event was the photos are of (e.g. Holiday 2010).

I hope someone knows of something more conventional and this isn't assumed to be too subjective a question to be on topic. Either way let me know. Thanks!

Comment: My 2 cents: you can have more than 9 season for some shows (ie CSI, The Simpsons, ...), so you might want to consider having it on 2 digits.

Comment: Interesting thought, that's probably a good idea. Under Windows mine are just stored 1,2,3,10,15,22 etc. Windows Explorer does natural sorting for numbers like this so that's not a problem but I'm not sure what Nix would do in this case?